# Close popup and navigate to another page in jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, popup

I'm trying to close a popup / dialog when a user presses a button inside the popup, and navigate to another page (single page application, multiple "pages").
jQM 1.4.0

If I tap the YES-button inside the popup, it will navigate to #page3 wich I want but then jump back to the startpage.
If I comment out the .popup("close"); it works, but I need to close the popup before I do stuff. What is wrong here?

js

```
$("#popupyes").on("tap", function(e)
    {
        $("#popupDialog").popup("close"); // <---- doesn't work

        //call some js-function before navigate to #page3
    });
```

html

```
<a href="#popupDialog" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-a">Button</a>

            <div data-role="popup" id="popupDialog" data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="a" data-dismissible="false" style="max-width:400px;">
                <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
                <h1>Head</h1>
                </div>
                <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
                    <h3 class="ui-title">Text.</h3>
                <p>Text?</p>
                    <a href="#page3" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-btn-a">No</a>
                    <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-delete" data-rel="back">Abort</a>
                    <a id="popupyes" href="#page3" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline">Yes</a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**Update** 
    I can use `$("#popupDialog").hide();` 
But then it's still in memory, only hidden... or wait, will it terminate by itself after a while?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply listen to `popupafterclose` to call any function after *popup* is completely closed.

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", function () {
    $("#popupID a").on("tap", function () {
        /* do something */
        $("#popupID").popup({
            afterclose: function () {
              /* do something */
            }
        }, "close");
    });
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/wH3uV/)**

Comment: Ah, perfect! Didn't know there was a special handler for that! :-)

Comment: @BakedInhalf `afterclose` and `afteropen` are handy ;)

Comment: Yes very! I've added afterclose :-) Works perfect