# Reloading/Refreshing a page in jQuery Mobile 1.4

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am making an AJAX call, and upon success I want to reload the current page that's on the screen.

I have tried

> $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change",
>   window.location.href, { allowSamePageTransition:true,
>   transition:'none', showLoadMsg:false, reloadPage:true } );

as well as

> window.location.reload();.

Both technically work but neither works properly. If I do the first line of code, the page refreshes, but what happens is for about half a second or so the original home page shows (the first page when you log into the app), then it refreshes and the page that the user is on shows again.

with window.location.reload(), the page reloads but a popup shows that says "Error Loading Page"....even though no JS errors are happening, and the page is reloading properly.

Any ideas on how I can get the page to just refresh as if I hit refresh in the browser?

I tried making a fiddle but it doesn't duplicate, either because I cannot make an ajax call, or because there is no other page to show in the background for that .5second period of time (or both maybe).

Comment: are you using _Single_ or _Multi-page model_?

Comment: every page is in a separate file

Comment: If you have all css and js in head of each page, your code should work with some modifications. Remove all options, and `reload: true`.

Comment: all of it is in each page file, like i said if i do a browser refresh everything works perfectly fine. I followed your advice and it still displays the original home page for about a second then the browser refreshes

Comment: Sorry, I meant add `reload: true`. `("change", "url", { reload: true });`.

Comment: that is exactly what i did

Comment: It shows homepage (not current page)?

Comment: What happens is, I press a button that makes an ajax call. the ajax call returns successfully. then if successful i call $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", window.location.href, { reload:true } );   ....the page that is currently showing disappears, then for about .5 seconds the homepage shows, then the browser refreshes and the correct page shows

Comment: actually sometimes the proper page shows and sometimes a blank white screen shows after the reload. In either case the URL is correct and when i do a browser refresh it shows the correct page

Comment: Ok, I understand now. Homepage is kept is navigation history and other pages are loaded via ajax. When you refresh, it goes back to homepage and replaces it with current page to make it act as Homepage.

Comment: well that's not appealing at all, it may confuse users. window.location.reload() or manually setting document.location.href works perfect except it shows "Error Loading Page" popup very briefly, and I have no idea why

Comment: If you have css and js in head of all pages, it should work fine with it. Try using this `window.location.href = window.location.href` instead of change page. It's weird that `.reload()` throws an error.

Comment: the problem may be related to the fact that I am closing a popup on ajax success also. I think it is trying to refresh and so am I

Comment: In this case, you should refresh after closing the popup because when popup is open, it adds parameters to URL. Try loading on `popupafterclose` event. This could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22534385/close-popup-and-navigate-to-another-page-in-jquery-mobile/22534894#22534894

Comment: It seems that on any page if i do  $("#idHere").popup( "close" ); after an ajax call, it changes my url, thus taking me away from the page. I have read it has something to do with the url technically being different...any chance you know how I can stop all popups from trying to change page if i call $("#photo-options").popup( "close" ); ???

Comment: Then you should call ajax after closing popup. There's a away to remove `&ui-state-dialog` but I don't have a laptop now to test it. console.log($.mobile) and go through object's properties. You should find it under on of the properties. Then `$.mobile.property = "";`.

Comment: I'd rather find a solution where closing the popup doesn't try to refresh at all because other parts of the app I am not needing a page reload but it is reloading anyway when i call $("#idHere").popup( "close" );

Comment: Ohhhh forgot something. Add `data-history="false"` to popup div.

Comment: ok I got it fixed...Craziest thing ever....I had to change the buttons from <buttons> to <a> .... When they were buttons it would cause a url change (had nothing to do with popup close call). the reason the home page was showing was because the button was causing a url change then the changepage call was bringing it back to the current page. WOW...crazy but its fixed

Comment: FYI I added a bug report here : https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/7268

Comment: Well done! this behaviour seems to occur also on page, not only popup.

Comment: Note: 'reloadPage' has been deprecated. It's now just 'reload'